# Determining if $@ is not present or empty

Tags: bash, arguments

I have a function, `get_flags`, that I use to parse arguments.  I source it in the file that I want to parse info and then pass the variables from the main program to the function using the `$@`.

It looks something like this

**myprogram.sh**

```
source arg_parser.sh
get_flags some_arguments more_arguments $@
```

I'd like a way to determine the difference between when there are no arguments to pass and when the programmer forgets `$@` at the end.  Or better yet a way to include the `$@` automatically.

For example

```
myprogram.sh -f flag1 -a flag2

#inside the program
get_flags some_arguments more_arguments #$@ has values, but was forgotten
```

versus

```
myprogram.sh #no arguments

#inside the program
get_flags some_arguments more_arguments $@  # $@ is present but empty
```

Comment: Why? Improper use of your function isn't your problem... Nice to do extra checking when you can, but I'm not sure I'd spend a lot of time on that.

Comment: Why not adding `[ -z &amp;quot;${@}&amp;quot; ] &amp;amp;&amp;amp; echo "Missing parameters..." && exit 1` inside your script

Comment: Side note: you should almost always use `"$@"` instead of `$@`, or the expansion is subject to word splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: Why not adding `[ -z "${@}"] && echo "Missing parameters..." && exit 1` inside your script to check if parameters are empties.

Comment: @PaulHodges it actually is my problem.  I write scripts for the people I work with, and when they don't use the right, i'm the one trouble shooting  most of the time, so it behooves me to make them as idiot proof as possible.

Comment: Fair enough. I always *require* an argument for any script simpler than "hello world", so if you have no arguments you want to pass I make you give me - or --, else I print a help/usage screen. As a side effect it means $@ will always have some testable value. If it doesn't, they did it wrong, and I print the instructions again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in your argument parser (`libfile.bash`):

```
__args=("$@")

myfunc () {
    echo "The positional parameters handed to the function:"
    printf '<%s>\n' "$@"

    echo "The global positional parameters:"
    printf '<%s>\n' "${__args[@]}"
}
```

Since it's sourced, it has access to the global positional parameters, which we read into the array `__args`, as within `myfunc`, `$@` refers to the positional parameters of the function.

Now, in your script (`script`), you use the parser like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. libfile.bash
myfunc localarg1 localarg2
```

And when using this from the command line as follows

```
./script globalarg1 globalarg2
```

you'd get this output:

```
The positional parameters handed to the function:
<localarg1>
<localarg2>
The global positional parameters:
<globalarg1>
<globalarg2>
```

demonstrating that you have access to the global positional parameters from within the function.

If you wanted `myfunc` to automatically append the global positional parameters to the local ones, you could do something like

```
__args=("$@")

myfunc () {
    set -- "$@" "${__args[@]}"
    echo "The positional parameters in the function:"
    printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
}
```

and you'd get

```
 ./script global1 global2
The positional parameters in the function:
<localarg1>
<localarg2>
<global1>
<global2>
```

Comment: Took me a little bit to understand what you were saying and how it worked, but this is actually better than what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    printf "\\nUsage: Put your usage here \\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

that's gonna check if the first argument ($1) is empty ("") and if it is then it's going to print the usage of your script and then exits with an error code(1) instead of (0) which is a peaceful exit.

Comment: The problem is that there are other arguments passed to the function before the $@.    I had your setup originally, but am trying to differentiate between when the user just doesn't pass arguments to the program, and when the programmer doesn't code right to pass to the arguments to the function.